# Move first element of Vector to last element

Tags: c++, gcc, move

I want to move first element of vector to the end of vector.

v = {1,2,3,4}
after this should be like this

v= {2,3,4,1}

my compiler version is gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1)

I know in Vc11 we can use std::move to move element. but how can I do this in above version of compiler?

Comment: You are looking for `std::rotate`.

Comment: Also, `std::move` does not move things in that sense. Anyway, there are good examples here: [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate).

Comment: Maybe a `std::deque` would be more appropriate of this.

Comment: Funnily enough, you can also call `remove(v.begin(), v.end(), v.at(0))` if there are no duplicates. I wouldn't do that, but... funnily enough. :)

Comment: @YamMarcovic That wouldn't work. At least it wouldn't be guaranteed to.

Comment: @juanchopanza You're right - it's not guaranteed that the elements will retain their original state.

Comment: @rodrigo why deque is more appropriate here?

Comment: @MuhammadZaighum: Because `deque` has efficient `pop_front()`/`push_front()` besides the `*_back()` variants, only available in `vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [`std::rotate` algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) in the standard library:

```
std::rotate(ObjectToRotate.begin(),
            ObjectToRotate.end()-1, // this will be the new first element
            ObjectToRotate.end());
```

Comment: For me this swaps the first and last elements instead of just moving the first item to the back.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, [std::rotate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) is one possible way:

```
std::rotate( v.begin(), v.begin() + 1, v.end() );
```

Comment: `std::vector` doesn't have a `pop_front()`, for a good reason. It would be quite inefficient.

Comment: Your new version would "work", but is unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: @juanchopanza Why, is it O(N)?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using std::rotate or if you want it the ugly way:
Create a function that safes the last and the first element in local variables, create a new local vector, but the last element as first in the vector. Put begin+1 till end-1 in the vector and then the first element.