# How to move the first element of a vector to the end of another

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

I have two vectors of the same type, shown below:

```
std::vector<Task*> ToRun;
std::vector<Task*> Completed;
```

When a `Task` is finished, it needs to be automatically moved from the `ToRun` vector container into the `Completed` vector.

**ToRun Vector contains** `TaskOne TaskTwo TaskThree ... TaskN`

**Completed Vector contains** `nothing`

After the first loop through the `ToRun` vector, both vectors should look like below:

**ToRun vector contains** `TaskTwo TaskThree ... TaskN`

**Completed Vector contains** `TaskOne`

The second loop through the `ToRun` vector should look like below:

**ToRun vector contains** `TaskThree ... TaskN`

**Completed Vector contains** `TaskOne TaskTwo`

I have the below code but I'm receiving the following error:

[image: Vector Moving Error]

Code snippet:

```
for (auto iter = ToRun.begin(); iter != ToRun.end(); iter++)
{
    (*iter)->dump(os);

    Completed.push_back(std::move(ToRun.front()));
    ToRun.erase(ToRun.begin());
}
```

I've tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004517/moving-elements-from-stdvector-to-another-one) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346056/move-first-element-of-vector-to-last-element) SO answer however I'm having no luck. From what is happening, I think that the iterator points to null after I've moved the front element.

Should I attempt to move the Task from one container to another and then `remove` instead of erase?

Comment: Why the `erase`? I.e., what is `ToRun` used for **other** than this?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf `ToRun` is simply a vector of specific Tasks to execute. The number of tasks depends on a configuration file so there may be a lot, or a little. I'm very inexperienced with STL containers and iterators so I've been exploring my options

Comment: Well, then there's no need to `erase` each item one at a time (which is quadratic time in the order you're doing it). Simply clear the vector at the end. Or do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erasing while iterating is always messy. If you erase the current element, how can `++` work?

Instead try

```
while (!ToRun.empty()) // loop until empty
{
    ToRun.front()->dump(os);

    Completed.push_back(std::move(ToRun.front()));
    ToRun.erase(ToRun.begin());
}
```

or something similar

But that's gross when you stop and think about it. Every `erase` shifts the rest of the elements in `ToRun` back one slot adding a large amount of unnecessary iterating and copying.

```
for (auto & run: ToRun) // or old school iterator if you prefer
{
    run->dump(os);
    Completed.push_back(std::move(ToRun.front()));
}
toRun.clear();
```

`clear` executes only once and obliterates the whole container in one shot. Much cleaner. Just one iteration to make sure the destructors are called, and you don't destroy pointers. Winning!

will have the same effect (assuming this isn't multithreaded, and if it is you have serious concurrency issues).

Cheersandhth.-Alf also brings up the point that since `ToRun` appears to contain pointers, `std::move` is not necessary. All that is being moved is a pointer, and that's trivial effort.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! A loop structure but without having to worry about the iterator.

Comment: Regarding efficiency, the `move` has no effect on a raw pointer, while the algorithm here is O(n^2).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It is pretty gross. I think an edit is in order. Thanks.

Comment: @SPrashad Cheersandhth.-Alf' s comment brought up a much better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

After this statement

```
ToRun.erase(ToRun.begin());
```

the iterator `iter` is invalid.

From the C++ Standard's description of the method `erase`

> 3 Effects: Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point
>   of the erase.